# What does "引いた" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've checked plentiful translations but none of them fit this word. They keep showing "Pulled out" but it's more of a word that means annoying or distasteful, I think. Can someone please clarify and direct me to a translation tool with accurate sentences?

Basically, it was two people chatting about pineapple on a pizza. One of them goes, "引いたか" and the other one says, "もちろん"

Comment: Would you include the full sentence?  As a stand alone word, I am inclined to go with the dictionaries until I can see something that leads to your potential conclusion.

Comment: What's the sentence *before* 引いたか? "Chatting about pineapples" does not explain why you thought it could mean "distasteful"...

Comment: Could be pulling the pineapples off, please provide more context.

Comment: Ah, okay, "pineapple on a pizza" is a longstanding argument! In Japanese, we have a longstanding [酢豚にパイナップル](https://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/11807365/)論争 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the person who said もちろん thinks having pineapple on a pizza is disgusting, right? If that is the case, 引いた is the ta-form (past tense) of the verb 引く, and one of its meanings is "to be turned off", "to be made to lose interest/passion/love", "to be dampened", "to wince", etc. So 引いたか means "Were you turned off?" I feel this meaning is particularly common in Kansai.

- 引くわー。 It turns me off!
- 引くなよ！ Hey, wait, listen!
- 2時間待つと聞いてちょっと引いた。 I flinched to hear I had to wait for two hours.

This slangy meaning is not listed in [the 19 definitions of 引く on jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F) (which is a bit surprising to me), but デジタル大辞泉 explains this as one of the 43(!) definitions of 引く:

> #### [引く](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/183987/meaning/m0u/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F/)
>
> ５㋕（俗語）相手に関心や興味を持たなくなる。相手から気持ちが離れる。「これを口にすると女性が引く」

And 明鏡国語辞典 第二版 says:

> #### 引く
>
> 〔俗〕冷ややかになる。しらける。「寒いギャグに引く」

See also:

- [What does ドン引き mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11162/5010)
- [What is the difference between 惹かれる and 引かれる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57663/5010)
- [引くわーって英語でなんて言うの？](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/28384/)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are misunderstanding what is going on here.  It would be helpful to see the sentence before the use of 引く, but given what we have, my answer will probably be a little anticlimactic.

引く, the present form of 引いた means [to pull](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F), among many other things.  When they are talking about pineapple on pizza, and you get the question:

> 引いたか

I would translate it as:

> Did (you) pull (the pineapple) off?

The implication may be that one of them dislikes pineapple on pizza, but that is *implied,* not explicitly stated.  You'll encounter this a lot in Japanese.  Context matters a *lot.*

The response of:

> もちろん
>  Of course.

verifies the implication that pineapple on pizza is disliked, but once again, it does not mean that the chosen verb of 引く means distasteful.